# Vbscript regex with variable length in the end

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm trying to return several matches (records?) from a string but seems like greedy regexp always takes first and includes all. Can I achieve as described below using regex?

**INPUT**:

```
<id:7/>Any text over here<id:8>Another text here (variable length and possibly including new line chars)<id:10>Yet another variable length string.
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

Regex matches, in this case 3 of them, that I'd like to see as separate matches from *VBScript.Regexp.Execute* method:

```
<id:7/>Any text over here
<id:8/>Another text here (variable length and possibly including new line chars)
<id:10/>Yet another variable 
length string including a new line.
```

So far I've tried the following regex but it will always return the full string as one match, and a bunch more I don't think make sense to include as they all have returned the same result:

```
<id:\d+/>(.|\n).*
```

Of course I can get the instances of each <id:999/> pattern using only

```
<id:\d+/>
```

Which returns something like

```
<id:7/>
<id:8/>
<id:10/>
```

But then I don't get the variable length text related to each id tag.

**NOTE:** Id tags are nothing of HTML nor XML, it's just the way records are delimited in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex:

```
<id:\d+\/>(?:.|\n)*?(?=<|$)
```

Only the `Global` flag set to `True` is required.

Explanation:
`<id:\d+\/>` Match the beginning of your records.
`(?:.|\n)*?` Non-capturing group of any character or newline, repeated zero-or-more times, but non-greedy
`(?=<|$)` Lookahead matching: match on ending character, either `<` or end-of-string, but don't include this match in final result.

You can try it here:
https://regex101.com/r/xUW90r/1

Answer (score 0):

You might use

```
<id:\d+\/?>[\s\S]*?(?=<id:\d+\/?>|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `<id:\d+\/?>` Match `<id:` then 1+ digits with optional `/` and `>`
- `[\s\S]*?` Match any char including newlines, as few as possitlbe
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `<id:\d+\/?>` Match `<id:` then 1+ digits with optional `/` and `>`
  - `|` Or
  - `$` End of string
- `)` Close lookahea

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DcOeio/1) without multiline.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your input with `vbCrLf` to insert Windows style newline characters in the string:

> `"<id:7/>Any text over here<id:8/>Another text here (variable length and " & vbCrLf & "possibly including new line chars)<id:10/>Yet another variable " & vbCrLf & "length string."`

I changed your regex to have two capture groups:

> `(<id:\d+/>)([^<]*)`

The first capture group `<id:\d+/>` matches the id. It is very similar to the regex you came up with.
The second capture group `[^<]` matches everything excluding the start of the next id which will pick up newline characters as well.

```vb
Rem rex.vbs
str = "<id:7/>Any text over here<id:8/>Another text here (variable length and " & vbCrLf & "possibly including new line chars)<id:10/>Yet another variable " & vbCrLf & "length string."
set rx = new RegExp
rx.Pattern = "(<id:\d+/>)([^<]*)"
rx.Global = True
set matches = rx.Execute(str)
For Each match in matches
  id=match.Submatches.Item(0)
  txt=match.Submatches.Item(1)
  WScript.Echo id & txt
Next
```

Here's me running the above:

```
C:\Temp>cscript /nologo rex.vbs
<id:7/>Any text over here
<id:8/>Another text here (variable length and
possibly including new line chars)
<id:10/>Yet another variable
length string.
```